# {System.Byte[]} to System.Byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, object, casting, getvalue

I have an object with one of its properties being an array of bytes.

I assign that property to object called `obj1`. When I assign that property to a variable, it acquires the `{System.Byte[]}` type which is an object, not an array.

As a result, I cannot access it. Problem is, whoever wrote the class did not define any `.GetValue()` method, so I cannot really access the elements, but the debugger watch shows the values!

The only methods defined for that object are `Equals`, `GetType` and `ToString` (which returns `System.Byte` and not the values).

I have tried the following without any luck:

```
var vals = (System.Byte[])obj1    //Returns a {System.Byte[]} object
var vals = (obj1 as System.Byte[])   //Returns a {System.Byte[]} object
var vals = obj1.GetValue           //Complains that GetValue is not defined
```

It is driving me crazy that I can see the array values using the watch window, but am having trouble accessing the elements.

Comment: What is the type of obj1? Can you print output for obj1.GetType()?

Comment: var vals = ((System.Byte[])obj1)[0]

Comment: What kind of problem are you facing to access the element?

Answer (score 0):

Your first two assignments are both correct and you should be able to access the array or its elements by using `vals[0]` or `vals.Length` etc

Comment: Thanks! I already tried indexing it like a normal array and that did not work. It was reassuring to hear it from someone else

Answer (score 0):

The debugger will see all values, including private, inaccessible values that you can't reference through code.  That's part of life in object oriented programming.  If you're really trying to access inaccessible data, there are a few ways you could access this data in your program:

- it's possible you can derive a class from the object you're trying to look at, and that class will have access to the hidden data.  This will happen if the original code had the data member's protection level as `protected`.
- You could use reflection to access the private data members, but that is far more advanced than I think what you're looking to do.

I wonder if you're simply looking for how to access data from the array?  If you want to get the data out of the byte array, just do a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++) {
    byte b = vals[i];
    // do something with b ...
}
```

You could also use `foreach`:

```
foreach (byte b in vals) {
{
    // do something with b ...
}
```

Check out [MSDN's Arrays tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx) for more information on arrays.  (Or just google `arrays tutorial c#` and pick your favorite reference site.)

Comment: Many thanks for your thorough reply.
I already tried indexing it like an array; it doesn't work.
Your comment about debugger clarified everything. I now know I should talk to the person who made the class. 
Sorry that my question was dumb; I hadn't coded in a "real" language for ~5 years.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem try something like this.

```
byte[] vByte = new byte[XLSStream.Length];
var stream = XLSStream.ToArray();
int count = 0;
foreach (var item in stream)
{
   vByte[count] = item;
   count++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to get image stored in MS SQL database in *image* format. I used an SQL request for it but it returned me that image as **object{System.Byte[]}**. I found a function to convert it to **byte[]**:

```
byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately the result was different from the original one and included *28 of extra bytes*. I compared both of arrays and find that this function adds **27 bytes from start** of array and **1 byte to the end** of array. 
I converted **byte[]** to **List** and deleted the extra bytes:

```
byte[] obj = ObjectToByteArray(queryObject);
            List<byte> list = obj.ToList();
            list.RemoveRange(0, 27);
            list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
            obj = list.ToArray<byte>();
```

I got an identical byte array as it stored in database. Then I converted it to an original image:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(obj);
            pictureBoxPhoto.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            pictureBoxPhoto.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

Maybe this way is specific but it works fine with images.